# anyway to get web browser window handle using php?

Tags: php, hwnd

I want know if there is a way to get current web browser window handle (HWND) using php, just like getting the browser information.

i dont want to get the browser handle like this using COM class

```
$Browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
```

Comment: No, this is outside the scope of PHP, the best you're going to get is the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] property to determine what browser the client is using. To collect things like browser desktop size, unfortunately its a task for JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I should have also asked is what you're developing reaching beyond the local environment of the computer running the PHP script?

Comment: @Scuzzy It is not impossible. get_browser() returns alot of information on the browser and operating system.

Comment: I've a feeling @Gaara is trying to achieve something beyond what PHP is designed to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `get_browser()`. [Check it out here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

Comment: It does not return the window handle.

Comment: @jpo It does contain information about the browser like you wanted, however. What are you trying to do with the handle?

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm just saying that the function does not do what he wants. I have no idea why he needs the window handle..

Comment: Right... sorry, didn't realize.

Comment: He most likely is trying to perform a Print Window functionality using PHP's `imagegrabwindow` function, since they only provide a means to do this with the IE Window Handle, there should be a means to do this with ALL Browsers.  Why would they provide this function otherwise??  To only support IE Browsers?  Highly unlikely.  I'm interested in this as well TBH!